# OM1 and OM3 Fiber Questions

Tags: fiber

We are looking to install OM3 fiber to get a through put of 10 gig throughout our facility. I am looking at a chart and it states that the OM3 (50/125) which I am guessing is multi-mode fiber can produce 10 gig @ 300 meters (SR) and 1 Gig @ 550 meters (SX) what does the SX and SR mean and I am assuming that the OM3 is a multi-mode fiber.

Answer (score 4):

Use OM4 please, seriously I've found it so much more stable at those speeds than OM3 and the price difference isn't so much.

Answer (score 1):

SR refers to [10GBASE-SR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10-gigabit_Ethernet#10GBASE-SR), and SX to [1000BASE-SX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#1000BASE-SX).

With an OM3 fiber, you can do ~300 meters at 10Gbit/s or ~550 meters at 1Gbit/s.

Answer (score -3):

Here's some information about Fiber Type vs. Speed and Distance:
[Fiber Type vs. Speed and Distance](http://www.lanshack.com/Fiber-Type-vs-Speed-and-Distance.aspx)

Comment: Please give a summary, the link might break any time.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.